# Use arrays in typescript classes

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add an array as one of my class properties, but I can't seem to find out how.

This is the code that I am currently trying.

```
export class Foo {
    id: number;
    value: number;
    array: [];
}
```

I have searched online to try to find the answer with no avail, so I thought I would ask here.

Comment: I am very new to both Angular and Typescript, so please bear with me if this is a silly question.

Comment: export class Foo {
    id: number;
    value: number;
    array = [];
}

Comment: array should be an array of some type, if you want to have an array of, for example strings, you may define property as "array:string[];"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in 2 different ways based on the Typescript documentation:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Once you have chosen the way you want to declare you array, you have to give it a type. Example: string, number, Observable, etc.

**Example 1:**

```
export class Foo {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  array: number[]
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
export class Foo {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  array: Array<number>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the documentation link and the other example!

Answer (score 3):

```
export class Foo {
    id: number;
    value: number;
    array: Array<>;
}
```

if you want an Array of specific type you can use for exemple:
`array: Array<string>` or `array: Array<number>` ...

Comment: Thank you! This solved my question and worked right when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You should define type items in that array. Some examples:

`array: number[]`
`array: string[]`
`array: any[]`

Comment: While this is a valid answer, using type "any" is bad practice. Thanks for contributing tho

Comment: @PatricioVargas it's not like Javascript would care. You do what you need to do, sometimes `any` is either required or even mandatory.

Comment: JS doesn't care about anything lol but it's best practice not mandatory. Read code from the the Angular website, read code on medium from the best angular devs and they dont use 'any'